# How to Rename standard field label 'Contact Name' on Case Object

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, standard-field

How to rename 'Contact Name' standard field on Case object.I don't see this field under Rename tabs and fields -> Tasks or Rename tabs and fields -->Activities.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GO to Rename Tabs and Labels 
and click on 'edit' Contact Object.
Rename the Field Label there.

[image]

Now that will reflect on Case Page as well.

[image]

Comment: In this case, it will rename the label at every location where the Contact is referred.

Comment: @Rohit, this solution is not feasible as it will reflect every place where contact is referred.

Comment: @RitzArlekar  Correct. So if you want to rename the Contact Name label only on Case object.. You have a workaround to create a Formula field and Name it accordingly on Case Object and Made it available on Detail page and Remove standard field. I can not think of any other available OOTB solution for this requirement.

HYPERLINK('/'+Contact.Id, 
       Contact.FirstName + ' ' + 
       Contact.LastName 
)